# How to insert icon just before the title and that too in the middle?

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, shortcode

Code for title without the icon:

```
[su_box title="<center>Title here</center>"  box_color="#000" radius="0"]

Box content

[/su_box]
```

Code for the icon:

```
[icon name="coffee" class="icon-2x"]
```

I want to insert the icon just before the title and that too in the middle! **JUST LIKE THIS ONE: [This One](http://prntscr.com/gcf3zv)**

I have tried to combine the codes and its not working for me as I am not good with coding!

Wordpress Plugin used:

Better Font Awesome

Shortcode Ultimate

Thanks.

Comment: Not working @Und3rTow.

I want like this one: http://prntscr.com/gcf3zv

Not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use shortcode for icon instead directly use icon tag. Kindly refer below code.

```
[su_box title="<center><i class='fa fa-coffee fa-2x'></i><br/><br/>Title here</center>" box_color="#000" radius="0"]
Box content[/su_box]
```